# Bad performance in the ui thread which TextToSpeech

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

My app record video and use [TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)->android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.[speak](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)() at the same time.

If I run in high device like 4 procesor at 1.5 ghz works ok. But if I use in 2 procesor 1.1 ghz device ui thread go very slow, with freezing of 2-6 seconds.

I know that problem is in TextToSpeech because if I don´t use it and record video the ui thread works very fluently in low device. If I use TextToSpeech + record video ui thread don´t work and also voice freeze 1-2 seg.

Is there any way to improve performance of TextToSpeech.speak()?

Comment: AsyncTask uses a shared single thread executor by default so its possible the TTS initialization is using an AsyncTask as well as the video recording. You probably want to create a single asynk task to record the video and use asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), params) to see if that unblocks the TTS initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using text to speech and video recording at the same time?  And you're surprised its slow?  Both of these take a non-trivial amount of CPU resources.  Some things just take processing power.  Try not using them at the same time and you'll get better results.

If you need to use them at the same time-  try using synthesizeToFile first to write the sound clip to a file, then playing the soundclip while recording.  This way you aren't trying to generate the phonemes at the same time as recording.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to 'Cores' when you say 'processors'? It seems like you are doing activities that should run on 3 different threads.

the Main Thread should be free always. Try not to bog it down... ever!

Extend the AsyncTask class. AsyncTask will allow you to do something that will take some lengthy amount of time without blocking the main thread.

Since this is all running on a virtual machine (Dalvik, to be precise), we must assume that threading is also virtual. This means that if you run 3 threads on two cores, the Virtual machine will decide which threads get processor cycles, and sometimes that means sharing cores.

I would say that if you ONLY plan on doing two heavy things at once, for a lower end device, you could implement this using the main thread for video, and a second thread for `TextToSpeech`. This isn't ideal because it potentially blocks the main thread. But since Video is the smoother of the two, it would be the first choice candidate for running on the Main UI Thread.

Ideally, you want minimum three threads, leaving the main UI Thread primarily unblocked. You can poll for results from both threads to detect completion.

If you happen to have 4 cores, then creating three threads should likely have more distributed performance over the available cores.

Some docs to get you going:
[Android Multithreading - a Qualcomm article](https://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/multi-threading-android-apps-multi-core-processors-part-1-2), and 
[Android: AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: speak is actually asynchronous, it sends the data to a separate process that handles the actual speaking.  You can actually change the program that it uses in settings.

Comment: Sadly, however...Passing the handing to an external process means you have little or no control over how the resources are actually used at runtime.